# Mockito - Mocking behaviour of a File

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a class that takes in a single file, finds the file related to it, and opens it. Something along the lines of

```
class DummyFileClass
{
    private File fileOne;
    private File fileTwo;
    public DummyFileClass(File fileOne)
    {
         this.fileOne = fileOne;
         fileTwo = findRelatedFile(fileOne)
    }

    public void someMethod()
    {
         // Do something with files one and two
    }

}
```

In my unit test, I want to be able to to test someMethod() without having to have physical files sitting somewhere. I can mock fileOne, and pass it to the constructor, but since fileTwo is being calculated in the constructor, I don't have control of this.

I could mock the method findRelatedFile() - but is this the best practice? Looking for the best design rather than a pragmatic workaround here. I'm fairly new to mocking frameworks.

Comment: It depends on what `someMethod()` is supposed to do. It returns void here. What is the effect of calling this method on subsequent interaction with your object?

Comment: Its not implemented yet, but the plan is to read a bit from the files on each invocation until they're both empty.

Comment: Mocking `File` is, err, well, hard. Why don't you want a test file? You can structure it so that it suit your test case(s) easily enough...

Comment: Mostly I just want to see if/how it could be done :) But for a more generic question, what if DummyFileClass was creating some other object? Is it poor form to try and mock the behavior of objects created internally (violating encapsulation?)?

Comment: Such objects normally do not define the _interface_ of your class; so you should not have to mock them in the first place ;) As to mocking `File` you could split your method into opening a file and opening an `InputStream` to that file. Mocking input streams is very easy (just make it return a `ByteArrayInputStream` with the contents of your choice)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In this sort of situation, I would use physical files for testing the component and not rely on a mocking framework. As `fge` mentions it may be easier plus you don't have to worry about any incorrect assumptions you may make of your mock.

For instance, if you rely upon [`File#listFiles()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29) you may have your mock return a fixed list of `File`s, however, the order they are returned in is not  guaranteed - a fact you may only discover when you run your code on a different platform.

I would consider using JUnit's [`TemporaryFolder`](http://junit.org/javadoc/4.9/org/junit/rules/TemporaryFolder.html) rule to help you set up the file and directory structure you need for your test, e.g.:

```
public class DummyFileClassTest {
    @Rule
    public TemporaryFolder folder = new TemporaryFolder();

    @Test
    public void someMethod() {
        // given
        final File file1 = folder.newFile("myfile1.txt");
        final File file2 = folder.newFile("myfile2.txt");

        ... etc...
    }
}
```

The rule should clean up any created files and directories when the test completes.

Comment: +1 PowerMock could mock the file but it is normally more trouble than its worth.

Comment: Cool, didn't know about TemporaryFolder, was using .deleteOnExit up until now :)