# Java and Junit integration test for file system

Tags: java, junit, integration-testing, spring-test

I have this class:

```
public class FooFileRepo {

@Override
public File getDirectory(String directoryPath) {
    ...     
    File directory = new File(directoryPath);
    ...
    return directory;
}

@Override
public void mkdirs(File f) {
    ...
    f.getParentFile().mkdirs();
}

public void writeFile(String path, String content) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException{
    ...
    try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(path, "UTF-8");) {
        writer.println(content);
    }
}
```

}

How can I mock filesystem operation, for writing unit tests for this class?

Thanks.

Comment: Have the file point to something in the test resources directory

Comment: No because I have also to test write file operation.

Comment: so use build/target directory for that and clean this directory after test

Answer (score 0):

Use **PowerMock**

```
       @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
       @PrepareForTest({ Printwriter.class })
       public class SampleTestClass {

        @Mock
        private PrintWriter mockPrintWriter;

        @Before
        public void init() throws Exception {
          PowerMockito.mockStatic(FileUtils.class);
        }

        @Test
        public void test() throws IOException {
        }   
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

For such a simple test it is probably better to use a real file system. As an alternative, you can build a facade to file operation and easily mock this facade.

https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/TemporaryFolder.html

```
public static class HasTempFolder {
@Rule
public TemporaryFolder folder= new TemporaryFolder();

@Test
public void testUsingTempFolder() throws IOException {
  File createdFile= folder.newFile("myfile.txt");
  File createdFolder= folder.newFolder("subfolder");
  // ...
 }
}
```

Also read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17164103/516167